# How to combine CASE, INNER JOIN, and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm dealing with an issue; I need to join two tables, group by their ID's and use CASE statement to compare values from those 2 tables. I have been trying to use a temp table and then SELECT from it.

Purpose is to test if values in CORE correspond to values in MART.

Ideally I want to have one query, where I will see column CORE_X_MART and can use where statement on it.

Group by is essential because otherwise I have ID duplicates in the temporary table.

My code:

```
drop table if exists #tNDWH_4034

select a.ID, b.ID, a.col2 as MART_Value, b.col2 as CORE_Value,
case when a.col2 = b.col2 then 'Match' else 'Mismatch' end as CORE_X_MART
into #tNDWH_4034
from       tab1 as a
inner join tab2 as b on a.ID = b.ID
where a.CurrentFlag = 1
group by a.ID, b.ID;
 
select * from #tNDWH_4034
where CORE_X_MART = 'Mismatch';
```

I'm using SQL server.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: `GROUP BY` is intended to be used with set functions (MAX(), SUM(), COUNT() etc.)

Comment: That's a `case` _expression_, not statement.

Comment: You say that `GROUP BY` is intentional, but you don't `GROUP BY` on all the columns you don't aggregate, and you don't aggregate *any* columns, so `GROUP BY` is certainly not required, and would cause an error as it stands.

Comment: In order to make duplicated values unique, you can try using [`DISTINCT`](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-select-distinct/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need temp table. You can go for derived table to achieve the purpose, to have them in a single query.

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(select a.ID, b.ID, a.col2 as MART_Value, b.col2 as CORE_Value,

case when a.col2 = b.col2 then 'Match' else 'Mismatch' end as CORE_X_MART

 from tab1 as a
 inner join tab2 as b 
 on a.ID = b.ID

where a.CurrentFlag = 1

group by a.ID, b.ID) as t
WHERE t.CORE_X_MART = 'Mismatch'
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
   select a.ID, b.ID, a.col2 as MART_Value, b.col2 as CORE_Value,
    
   case when a.col2 = b.col2 then 'Match' else 'Mismatch' end as CORE_X_MART
    
   into #tNDWH_4034
    
   from tab1 as a
   inner join tab2 as b on (a.ID = b.ID)
    
    where a.CurrentFlag = 1
    
    group by a.ID, b.ID, a.col2, b.col2
,case when a.col2 = b.col2 then 'Match' else 'Mismatch' end --this line is probably not required
```

Comment: Since the pourpose is to check if there is match between values in table A and B, i suggest a LEFT JOIN, so you can see also the ID in A not in B (they will come out as Mismatch as `value = NULL` is false in the CASE)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the temp table, group by, or the case either. You are looking for mismatches only so just use the not equal to operator `<>` to filter your results.

```
select distinct a.ID, a.col2 as MART_Value, b.col2 as CORE_Value
from       tab1 as a
inner join tab2 as b on a.ID = b.ID
where a.CurrentFlag = 1
and a.col2 <> b.col2
```